# Running first android application on mobile device

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android. I have started developing my first application following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html). I know the document is self-explanatory. But, I am out of the way somewhere.

I have connected my Mobile to my laptop through a USB cable, and My OS is Windows. When I try to run my application(I mean the [basic](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) application) as an Android Application option from Eclipse. Initially, I am facing a Confirmation box titled : Android AVD Error, as shown below.

[image]

As I certainly, don't want to create a virtual device, I have selected No and below is the output.

```
[2014-09-12 22:50:41 - SRK] ------------------------------
[2014-09-12 22:50:41 - SRK] Android Launch!
[2014-09-12 22:50:41 - SRK] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-12 22:50:41 - SRK] Performing com.srk.main.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-12 22:50:41 - SRK] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.4W'.
[2014-09-12 22:50:43 - SRK] Performing com.srk.main.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-12 22:50:48 - SRK] Launch canceled!
```

I would like to see it run on my mobile. I am trying to run it on Mobile of make [MOTOG](http://www.motorola.com/us/moto-g-pdp-1/Moto-G-%281st-Gen.%29/moto-g-pdp.html)

Comment: download pda.net software

Comment: Install the appropriate USB driver for your phone. This site has links to a number of phones. http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the driver for your specific device and enable USB debugging mode in your phone's settings under developer options.

Comment: Sometimes simple things cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Download moborobo from the link :

http://mobomarket.moborobo.com/m/android2/

No matter what device you are using just plug your device it will automatically detect your device.

Answer (score 0):

Download moborobo from the link :

http://mobomarket.moborobo.com/m/android2/

No matter what device you are using just plug your device it will automatically detect your device.

Note:- enable debugging mode from developer option